# Do we sense the mental stream (santāna)

Tags: rebirth, terminology

Do we sense the ['mindstream' (citta-santāna)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mindstream)?

Or is it inferred?

I think it is inferred, and that this means we cannot say "I will die", except as a fictionalized explanation.

But, is it inferred? And anyway, what do Buddhists say about explanations ?

Comment: Is santana the same as dharma? Can you provide a definition or a link to a definition - I'm struggling to understand the question to be honest and maybe others would appreciate some clarification too. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm this is where psychiatry start picking drugs for us... Keep in mind that is is purely theoretical until the Haldon Collider find evidence of other dimensions...

Mind and brain are not the same, but connected like two wheels learning against each others edges. So one might call it two different species. The Buddha spoke of 31 planes of existence, which could be understood as 31 universes. Universes would then also move and overlap each other. If overlapping, a nexus is created in which reactions happen. Now imagine that somehow that because of the nexus, the brain has an attraction on another species and this other species attached itself to the brain like a parasite... It would mean that if we are Citta, then we are the aliens from another universe experiencing this universe through the senses of a body...

But we lack so much data on so much to actually make technical descriptions on how it works... Much right now is just thesis stage. Nothing more.

It is said that you will get this experience in the ninth Jhana...

Comment: If you are talking about the particleaccelerator in CERN its called "Large Hadron Collider" or short LHC.

Comment: Argh! Yes - Thank you for the correction :)